# Websockets for Android Chat Application

Tags: android, sockets, websocket

I am interested in building a real time chat application for an Android and possibly an iPhone app. I have done some background research on websockets and they appear to be a reasonable option. However, noting that a message can be sent to a user at anytime, as is commonplace for a chat application, the socket for the client server connection would then never be allowed to close or else the user would be cut off from any stream of information and new messages.

I am curious, would there be detrimental consequences to building out my apps in this manner using permanent open connections for the sockets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main downside on the client is the battery drain for the radio, since this needs to keep up the data connection. Note that this is the same for any solution which tries to do push, so there's no real difference between WebSockets and e.g. HTTP long poll. If you want messages to arrive immediately, you need a connection.

On the server, the main cost is RAM. WebSocket servers are designed so that, unlike HTTP servers, they don't use one thread per connection, so scaling up to massive amounts of parallel connections is not problematic per se.

Comment: In any communication app, such as Whatsapp, battery drain can occur. Is the battery drain substantial such that it would prevent building out a a chat app using websockets?

Comment: @Sauron - I don't have any numbers there. A lot depends on what latency you're willing to accept. If the connection is unused, then the radio falls into energy saving state, and on receiving a message it can take a few seconds to go back to a fast transfer state. If you're e.g. using pings to keep the connection fast permanently, then this drains significantly more battery than allowing the radio to do its energy saving thing.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use the socket connection only when the app is in foreground and once the app goes to background fallback to GCM to wake up the device and then establish socket connection again. This way, the app is not take much battery. Also, I doubt whether iOS will allow the socket connection for a long duration.
Here is a sample code for a building a chat which uses both socket connection and push notification
https://github.com/AppLozic/Applozic-Android-SDK